# Adding EJB interceptors with custom annotations

Tags: java, ejb, interceptor

I have a number of EJB3.0 interceptors that require additional configuration. So far I have been simply adding the interceptors via `@Interceptors( { MyInterceptor.class } )` and then added a second, custom annotation like `@MyInterceptorConfiguration(value=something)`.

This is rather tedious though. Is it possible to annotate a custom annotation so that it will trigger the addition of an Interceptor? Ideally I would like to just add `@DoMyInterception(config=foo)` to a class and have that add my interceptor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is only possible with CDI [stereotype](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/1.0.0/en-US/html/stereotypes.html) annotations (see the [interceptor bindings](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.0/html/interceptors.html) page for examples) in EE 6 (EJB 3.1).

Comment: That's what I was afraid might be the case. Oh well, time to speed up our migration to EE6 then. Thanks for your answer!