# How to ensure annotations execution order in java?

Tags: java, spring, annotations

i have 2 custom annotations, but one should always executed before the other. How do i ensure this? Is there some kind of ordering or do it with additional method definitions?

Comment: whats happening ? works randomly ?

Comment: It seems, that annotations descriptions in `Class` are stored in `HashMap`. This is not guarantee native order, of course. So, I think, there is no way.

Comment: What do you mean about execution order? How annotations are processed depends on the code that uses them. What are you annotating? Which annotations are you using?

Comment: If they are custom annotations, custom code probably processes them, so, you could easily direct the order in said custom code of yours.

Comment: They are annotations, which i made. How do i direct the order with custom code? Do you have any example?

Comment: Well what about method 1: process annotation 1, followed by method 2: process annotation 2. voilá.

Comment: What actually you mean by `annotation` execution? Where?

Comment: I think the real issue here is what you're doing that requires order-specific handling. That to me is a code smell. As @U-No-Poo says, if it's a custom annotation, you must have some annotation processor anyways which can impose an ordering regardless of which annotations are present.

Comment: Could you post me a link with custom annotation processor code please.

Comment: How the jvm decides which annotation to process first?

Comment: If they are custom annotations, nothing except your own code will handle and process them. How should anything else know what to do with them? If you are unsure how to do it with annotations, maybe another approach would be better suited?

Comment: OK, i have to separate handlers - aspects which have such method:
    @Around("@annotation(myannocation)")
 public Object invoke(final ProceedingJoinPoint invocation, final Myannocation myannocation) throws Throwable {
}


Do you call this "my own code"? How do i ensure that myannocation1 invoke method is executed before myannocation2 invoke method?

Answer (score 9):

You can ensure the order of your custom annotations with @Order annotation.

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/annotation/Order.html

Example:

First annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface CustomAnnotation {
}

@Aspect
@Component
@Order(value = 1)
public class CustomAnnotationInterceptor {

    @Before("@annotation(customAnnotation )")
    public void intercept(JoinPoint method, CustomAnnotation customAnnotation ) {
        //Code here
    }
}
```

Second annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface CustomAnnotationTwo {
}

@Aspect
@Component
@Order(value = 2)
public class CustomAnnotationInterceptorTwo {

    @Before("@annotation(customAnnotationTwo )")
    public void intercept(JoinPoint method, CustomAnnotationTwo customAnnotationTwo ) {
        //Code here
    }
```

Using them:

```
@CustomAnnotationTwo
@CustomAnnotation
public void someMethod(){
}
```

In this example, CustomAnnotationInterceptor will execute first.

Answer (score 2):

From http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-ataspectj-advice-ordering

Spring AOP follows the same precedence rules as AspectJ to determine the order of advice execution. The highest precedence advice runs first "on the way in" (so given two pieces of before advice, the one with highest precedence runs first). "On the way out" from a join point, the highest precedence advice runs last (so given two pieces of after advice, the one with the highest precedence will run second).

When two pieces of advice defined in different aspects both need to run at the same join point, unless you specify otherwise the order of execution is undefined. You can control the order of execution by specifying precedence. This is done in the normal Spring way by either implementing the org.springframework.core.Ordered interface in the aspect class or annotating it with the Order annotation. Given two aspects, the aspect returning the lower value from Ordered.getValue() (or the annotation value) has the higher precedence.

When two pieces of advice defined in the same aspect both need to run at the same join point, the ordering is undefined (since there is no way to retrieve the declaration order via reflection for javac-compiled classes). Consider collapsing such advice methods into one advice method per join point in each aspect class, or refactor the pieces of advice into separate aspect classes - which can be ordered at the aspect level.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is very old question, but I just wanted to document my findings. Can anyone please confirm if these are correct?
It is already mentioned in this page that Spring documentation says that execution of annotations is undefined unless @Order annotation is used.
I tried to rename the Aspect classes, and tested many times, and found that Aspect classes are executed in alphabetical order of their names and found that the result is consistent.

Below is my sample code:

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface A {}

@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface B {}

@Aspect
public class A_Aspect {

@Around("@annotation(mypackage.A)")
public void around(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) {
    System.out.println("A_Aspect");
    joinPoint.proceed();
    }
}

@Aspect
public class B_Aspect {

    @Around("@annotation(mypackage.B)")
    public void around(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) {
        System.out.println("B_Aspect");
        joinPoint.proceed();
    }
}

class AdvisedClass{
    @B
    @A
    public void advisedMethod(){}
}
```

When I tried to execute advisedMethod(), following are the logs I received:

```
A_Aspect
B_Aspect
```

I changed annotation declaration sequence:

```
@A
@B  
public void advisedMethod(){}
```

Following are the logs:

```
A_Aspect
B_Aspect
```

I renamed Annotation @A to @C, Following are the logs:

```
A_Aspect
B_Aspect
```

But, when I tried to rename Aspect class A_Aspect to C_Aspect, Following are the logs:

```
B_Aspect
C_Aspect
```

As I said, I want someone to confirm this as I could not find any documentation for this

Answer (score 1):

Checkout https://stackoverflow.com/a/30222541/810109: At least in Java 8 you can retrieve annotations in a guaranteed order, so you just have to declare them in the right order.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using EJB interceptors.

you can simply add interceptors via @Interceptors( { MyInterceptor.class } )  and then add for second one @MyInterceptorConfiguration(value=something).

As bkail says in [their answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11326862/adding-ejb-interceptors-with-custom-annotations/11330748#11330748):

> This is only possible with CDI stereotype
>   annotations (see the interceptor
>   bindings page for examples) in EE 6 (EJB 3.1).

Comment: This might help you,                                   http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/apt/index.html                                                                                  code appropriate for the annotation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460001/can-java-annotations-help-me-with-this/1460047#1460047                                                           Try this way

Comment: When you copy the words of others, you must always provide proper credit. I've edited the above to show you how this is done.

Answer (score 0):

First annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface FirstAnnotation {
  String value() default "";
}
```

Second annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface SecondAnnotation {
  String value() default "";
}
```

Usage example:

```
public class Test {

  @SecondAnnotation("second annotation")
  @FirstAnnotation("first annotation")
  private String annotatedField1 = "value of field 1";

  @SecondAnnotation("second annotation")
  @FirstAnnotation("first annotation")
  private String annotatedField2 = "value of field 2";

  @SecondAnnotation("second annotation")
  private String annotatedField3 = "value of field 3";

  @FirstAnnotation("first annotation")
  private String annotatedField4 = "value of field 4";

  // Sample
  public static void processAnnotatedFields( final Object obj ) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {

    for ( final Field field : getFieldsFornAnotation( obj, FirstAnnotation.class ) ) {
      // Do something with fields that are annotated with @FirstAnnotation
      final FirstAnnotation an = field.getAnnotation( FirstAnnotation.class );
      System.out.print( "@" +an.annotationType().getSimpleName()+ "(" +an.value()+ "): " );
      System.out.println( field.getName()+ " = '" +field.get(obj)+ "'" );
    }

    System.out.println();

    for ( final Field field : getFieldsFornAnotation( obj, SecondAnnotation.class ) ) {
      // Do something with fields that are annotated with @SecondAnnotation
      final SecondAnnotation an = field.getAnnotation( SecondAnnotation.class );
      System.out.print( "@" +an.annotationType().getSimpleName()+ "(" +an.value()+ "): " );
      System.out.println( field.getName()+ " = '" +field.get(obj)+ "'" );
    }

  }

  /**
   * Collect object fields annotated with "annotationClass"
   * This can be saved in static map to increase performance.
   */
  private static final Set<Field> getFieldsFornAnotation( final Object o, final Class<? extends Annotation> annotationClass ) {
    final Set<Field> fields = new LinkedHashSet<Field>();

    if ( o == null || annotationClass == null )
      return fields;

    for (final Field field : o.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
      if (field.isAnnotationPresent(annotationClass)) {
        field.setAccessible( true );
        fields.add( field );
      }
    }
    return fields;
  }

  public static void main(final String[] args) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {

    processAnnotatedFields( new Test() );

  }

}
```

Result/output:

```
@FirstAnnotation(first annotation): annotatedField1 = 'value of field 1'
@FirstAnnotation(first annotation): annotatedField2 = 'value of field 2'
@FirstAnnotation(first annotation): annotatedField4 = 'value of field 4'

@SecondAnnotation(second annotation): annotatedField1 = 'value of field 1'
@SecondAnnotation(second annotation): annotatedField2 = 'value of field 2'
@SecondAnnotation(second annotation): annotatedField3 = 'value of field 3'
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes I think Annotation itself provide annotation for that like @First, and @Second etc. so you can try that

Comment: You think so or you checked it? :)