# How can i change the execution order of annotations in Spring?

Tags: spring, aop, spring-annotations

I have a custom annotation @MyAnnotation

```
@Documented
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD })
public @interface MyAnnotation {
  String [] roles() default {};
}
```

And i'm using my annotation as

```
@MyAnnotation
@RequestMapping(value = "/test/xyz", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String myFunc(@Valid TestClass test) {
    return "Name: " + test.getName();
}
```

I want to execute my custom annotation @MyAnnotation before @Valid annotation from Javax as i'm performing some security checks in my annotation implementation and those need to be performed before validating the body.

Is there a way through which i can increase priority of my custom annotation so that it gets executed before @Valid annotation?

Answer (score 0):

You can use @Order: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/annotation/Order.html

Similar question:
[How to ensure annotations execution order in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14318438/how-to-ensure-annotations-execution-order-in-java)

Comment: This works when you have both the annotations as custom annotations and you provide your ordering to the annotations. But the problem here is how do i override the priority so that my custom annotation gets executed before the javax @valid annotation? Basically i want to preauthorize before validating.

Comment: Have you ever got it resolved @SalmanKhan?